# Laravel 4 Migration Fails to add a foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, migration

I'm trying to add a new table to a laravel 4x project that has a foreign key reference back to a primary key in an existing table that already has data.

Here is my migration file for adding the new table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomResponsesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('custom_responses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned();
        $table->dateTime('created')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('last_changed')->nullable();
        $table->string('response_type')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('custom_response')->nullable();
    });

    Schema::table('custom_responses', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('properties');
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('custom_responses');
}
}
```

However I've also tried having a migration file like this

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCustomResponsesTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('custom_responses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->dateTime('created')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('last_changed')->nullable();
        $table->string('response_type')->nullable();
        $table->mediumText('custom_response')->nullable();
        $table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned();            
        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('properties');
    });

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('custom_responses');
}
}
```

When I look at the existing properties table I see

[image]

But when I try and run the migration I get

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                                   
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `custom_responses` add constraint custom_responses_hotel_id_foreign foreign key (`hotel_id`) references `properties` (`id`))  

[PDOException]                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

From scanning similar questions on SO, as well as googling the error the typical causes are mismatched datatypes, or the new table being MyISAM when only InnoDB supports foreign keys.  From everything I can see the new table is being created InnoDB and the datatypes match.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Does `properties` use the `InnoDB` engine?